# What am I missing in my Laravel Sanctum Setup?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

I am trying to set up Laravel Sanctum out of the box. I have barely changed a thing from the fresh install.

What I have done:

-Created a user and generated a token for them:

```
$token = Auth::user()->createToken('TestToken');
```

This works the token show up in the data base as expected.

-Added routes to my api.php

```
Route::get('testAPI', function () {
    return 'API CONNECTED';
});


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/testAuth', function () {
    return 'AUTHENTICATED';
});
```

Using postman the testAPI route works.

However the calling the testAuth route returns what appears to be a blank Laravel view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title inertia>Laravel</title>
...blah blah....
```

Note: the page return is NOT the Laravel error page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="theme-light">
<!--
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'Route'
...blah blah for reference...
```

The page returned remains unchanged regardless of adding the bearer token to the header.
What am I missing, any help appreciated :)

UPDATE: as per @ceejayoz comment I have added `Accept: application/json` to my headers. Now I am receiving a reponse of:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

Additionally, I have tried adding `Referer: 127.0.0.1:8000`,this still results in Unauthenticated

Comment: Try adding a `Accept: application/json` header. My suspicions is authentication wasn't successful and it's trying to redirect you to the login.

Comment: I didn't think of the redirect to web login. Thank you, I would have never found that small addition. That got me one step closer. Now it is just returning `"message": "Unauthenticated"`

Answer (score 0):

For the authentication header in postman, please follow this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCW7L.png).
And If need more information about how to setup laravel sanctum, please follow https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum laravel docs. There can be nothing better than Laravel docs for setting up Laravel sanctum

Comment: As mention in my post - I have already added the bearer token to the header. I did indeed follow the docs to get as far as I have. However, now I have run into an issue I cant fix without extra help